# In Ruby, Unexpected Result When Calculating Number e

Tags: ruby

In ruby, I try to calculate e with its explicit formula:

> `(1+(1/t))**t`

In irb, i write down this

> `(1.0+(1.0/100000000000000))**100000000000000`

gives me 2.716110034087023 near to e,as i expected. And i try to increase
a number 10th times.

> `(1.0+(1.0/1000000000000000))**1000000000000000`

gives me 3.035035206549262 and not near to e. (Un expected result). Ok than, i try to increase the number a 10th times more.

> `(1.0+(1.0/10000000000000000))**10000000000000000`

this result is 1.0 - (Ok this is may be the language boundry)

But, What is the meaning of unexpected result 3.035035206549262? Is this a bug or what?

Comment: My ruby version is ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Just for completeness sake, you do realize that Ruby has a constant `Math::E`, right?

Comment: Yes, right. I just want to know the unexpected result. If i will need to e for calculating, i will use the Math::E.

Comment: This should help: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the meaning of unexpected result 3.035035206549262? Is this a bug or what?

There's only a finit number of representable floating point numbers and each real number has to be rounded towards its closest floating point number.

For `t = 10 ** 14`, the term `1+(1/t)` should be `1.00000000000001`, but it actually is:

```
1.0000000000000099920072216264088638126850128173828125
```

It's still quite close, the difference is:

```
  1.00000000000001
- 1.0000000000000099920072216264088638126850128173828125
--------------------------------------------------------
  0.0000000000000000079927783735911361873149871826171875
```

Finishing the calculation with that approximation gives:

> 1.00000000000000999<sup>100,000,000,000,000</sup> ≈ 2.71611003409

For `t = 10 ** 15` however, the closest floating point value is:

```
1.0000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
```

The difference is much larger:

```
  1.000000000000001
- 1.0000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
--------------------------------------------------------
- 0.0000000000000001102230246251565404236316680908203125
```

And that approximation gives:

> 1.00000000000000111<sup>1,000,000,000,000,000</sup> ≈ 3.03503520655

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug, it's how [floats](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html) behave.
Ruby floats are [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), so you cannot expect any precise result when your formula uses 1E-15 or smaller values.

It's also the reason why banks don't work with floats but with integers representing a smaller unit (e.g. cents).

If you want to calculate `e`, you could use another formula (e.g. [the sum of infinite series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))), which doesn't depend on very small floats with very large powers. As a bonus, it converges pretty fast, so 17 terms are enough for float precision :

```
fact = 1.0

e = (1..17).inject(1) do |mem, i|
  fact *= i
  mem + 1/fact
end

puts e
#=> 2.7182818284590455

puts e-Math::exp(1)
#=> 4.440892098500626e-16
```

[`BigDecimal`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) could also be an alternative, but it won't help much for a formula which basically is [`1**∞`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form).

There is [`BigMath`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigMath.html), however. This outputs 1000 significant digits of `e` :

```
BigMath.exp(1,1000).to_s('F')
#=> 2.718281828459045235360......
```

Comment: 17 iterations are sufficient. But due to floating point inaccuracy (during the intermediate operations) your result is slightly off. The float value closest to _e_ is `2.718281828459045`.